# does jupyter notebook works offline in windows, if so then how?

Tags: jupyter-notebook

I want to install jupyter notebook on my windows. But I have heard that this notebook works in browser. Is there any way to download it so that it can works offline in my pc? I dont want to use it with internet connection. Any download link and suggestion will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you don't need an internet connection to run jupyter notebook because it runs on the localhost.

after you install anaconda you will get options like below image

- [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vgvrT.png)
- step 1: click on anaconda prompt
- step 2: type jupyter-notebook or jupyter notebook (both way works)
  after few second it opens your browser automatically and you can see the home page of jupyter notebook

Comment: How to do that? Any download link

Comment: first, install anaconda from the official website https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/install/windows/ where you will get the Jupyter notebook installed in the anaconda navigator  from the navigator you can directly start jupyter notebook

Comment: And after that?

Comment: how to do that without anaconda. I have just python installed. Can I use this using pip?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need an internet connection to run Jupiter notebooks for example while using conda. The browser is simply used for display purposes. You can also try out VSCode for having Jupiter notebook-like experience. You will need an internet connection if you are connecting your jupyter notebooks with a remote machine though I doubt that's the case with you.

Comment: Please if you can send downoad link of this by which I can download it for offline purposes, then it would be a great help. And I will then mark your answer as solution to this problem

Comment: I am not sure which download link you are referring to. Here is the link to vscode that I use.  https://code.visualstudio.com/ . You can simply create a file_name.ipynb and use it like your regular Jupiter notebook or use anaconda and launch a notebook from terminal